Parallel Computing and usage of CPUs
I have a conceptual question. I have a MATLAB code for simulating a beam propagation (optics) which has lots of for loops inside it but every iteration in a loop depends on the previous one (n+1 th iteration depends on the values from nth iteration). As I understood it means that the loops are not suitable for parallel computing, i.e. I cannot use parfor instead of for. Does that mean when I send my job using batch to the node of a cluster, I am only using 1 core in that node?
I tried to send the same code with requesting 28 and 56 cores separately and there was no time difference in run time. ChatGPT told me that it's because my code does not support parallel computing and I'm only using one core.
Is there a faster way other than parallel computing if I won't be able to use it?
Edit
This image shows the lines where most of the work is done in my code 
Lines 193 and 195 are shown here and in this double for loop
   for j = 3:Nz
        %u(1,j) = u_o(1,j-2) + (-1i/(2*k_0))*(4*(dz(j-2)+dz(j-1))/( (dr(i-1)+dr(i))/2 )^2)*( u_o(2,j-1) - u_o(1,j-1) ) + ...
        %    (dz(j-2)+dz(j-1))*( -1i*w*u_o(i,j-1)*( n_Kerr*I_o(1,j-1) - n_e*(N(1,j-1)+N_ei) - n_h*(N(1,j-1)+N_hi) )/c - ...
        %        u_o(1,j-1)*( alpha(1,j-1) + beta(1,j-1)*I_o(1,j-1) + sigma_e(1,j-1)*(N(1,j-1)+N_ei) + sigma_h(1,j-1)*(N(1,j-1)+N_hi) )/2 ); 
        for i = 2:(Nr-1)
            u(i,j) = u_o(i,j-2) + (-1i/(2*k_0))*((dz(j-2)+dz(j-1))/( (dr(i-1)+dr(i))/2 )^2)*( (1-1/(2i))*u_o(i-1,j-1) + (1+1/(2i))*u_o(i+1,j-1) - 2*u_o(i,j-1) ) + ...
                (dz(j-2)+dz(j-1))*( -1i*w*u_o(i,j-1)*( n_Kerr*I_o(i,j-1) - n_e*(N(i,j-1)+N_ei) - n_h*(N(i,j-1)+N_hi) )/c - ...
                u_o(i,j-1)*( alpha(i,j-1) + beta(i,j-1)*I_o(i,j-1) + sigma_e(i,j-1)*(N(i,j-1)+N_ei) + sigma_h(i,j-1)*(N(i,j-1)+N_hi) )/2 );      
        end
        u(Nr,j) = u(Nr-1,j); u(1,j) = u(2,j); % Neumann boundary  
    end

which is itself in the main for loop (time loop). And line 213 is in this double for loop
   for i= 2:Nr-1
        for j = 2:(Nz-1)
        u(i,j) = u(i,j) + v*(u(i,j-1) + u(i,j-1) - 2*u(i,j))/2;
        end
    end

which is also in the main time for loop. As you can see there are dependencies between iterations and I'm really not an expert in this field (I'm a physics undergrad) but it seems like it's not parallelizable.

If your MATLAB code is sequential (you didn’t program it specifically to use parallelism) then it’s not going to magically be parallel just because you run it on a cluster. Some of the MATLAB commands you call can potentially use multithreading internally, but that typically only scales across a few (say 10) cores, depending on thradding more cores will hardly be noticeable. And that

With all due respect, what has lead you to an assumption a hardcoded TEXT-transformer, specialised only to seek (by nothing else but by a "fear" to get least penalty for past "examples" of transformed TEXT) in the most masochistic manner ever seen any new least bad TEXT (according again only to anticipation from past penalties "received" in "training" - if someone remembers a regular beating of kids at scholastic "schools" with cane whenever kids answer not an exact latin TEXT memorized w/o any level of understanding a bit of meaning = exactly the "learn"-by-beating GPT ) "KNOWS" anything?

would it be possible to enlighten readers with some of your code? I agree with Luengo, if you tell 'one by one' the computer will do that. BUT if you rewrite your code in matrix notation, skipping for loops writing 'compact' MATLAB instead of all-data-single-line C/C++ , then the cluster has a bigger picture of the task to solve.

and i hope you don't mind me asking : the wiggy guy in the picture, is Sir Isaac Newton? or Huygens?

@JohnBofarullGuix ofc I don't mind. The wiggy guy in the picture should be Isaac Newton, at least it was what I intended but I'm not sure :) And I will try to put a snippet of the lines where the most of the work is done in my code and may be parallelizable.

There are different types of parallel computing. In your case, what you're doing sounds like a typical "ODE-style" problem where you're propagating a system in time. Generally, these are challenging to parallelise. Probably your best bet is instead of trying to parallelise over time-steps, try and use data-parallelism to run each time-step more quickly.
This approach only really works well if each time-step exposes a lot of possibly-parallel computations. If you're working with FFT-based optical propagation, you can perhaps use distributed arrays to make a data-parallel approach. Data parallelism on the CPU like this can be hard to get good speedup. Using gpuArray (if possible) might be more appropriate.

You can use parfor on your outer loop so that each independent case (index) runs in its own core/thread.
Also read this
variables in parfor loops
if you want you can add a sample code and we can help more.

No, you can not. This is the core of OP’s problem. If loop iteration n depends on the result of iteration n-1, then you cannot also a parfor on it.
